# How to generate value look like a line

Tags: excel, interpolation

I want to generate more values between certain of ranges data, below is my data:

```
X           Y
0.5044      0.4344
0.491721    0.432822
0.4811      0.4315
0.491673    0.414895
0.4701      0.4128
0.4798      0.3967
0.46945     0.3954
0.4591      0.3941
```

This data generates 8 dots in the graph, but I want to create more values between each point so that the data looks like a rectangular box. I manually created some of the data between the first two rows for X and Y. Example:

```
X           Y
0.5044      0.4344
0.5022      0.434    <-- added
0.495       0.4333   <-- added
0.4988      0.4338   <-- added
0.502       0.43     <-- added
0.499       0.425    <-- added
0.4953      0.42     <-- added
0.491721    0.432822
```

I want more values to link the data together, so the graph looks like a line 
between the dots. Is it possible to do in such a way?

Comment: What you want is called interpolating, but it usually only "fills the gap", in your case there seems to be some logic to it. The values goes both up and down.

Comment: A screenshot of your plot "before" and "after" would be useful here.

Comment: @Andreas my logic is to create more value and it will look like a line, my data got 8 dots, i wish to create more dots and it will abit look like a rectangular

Comment: @TimWilliams i dont know how to put a screenshot here, it said need to put the url to read the image

Comment: Upload your screenshot to a sharing site, then post the URL to the image in your question.

Comment: @TimWilliams i have upload the image to https://postimg.org/image/z4z1hfw2f/, isn't possible to generate more dots like expected result screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have plotted separate series for the sake of colour differentiation, you may prefer to add cells as new points instead.

The blue dots are from charting A1:B9:

[image: SO39158313 example]

I then took the average of adjacent X and Y readings (in C3:D9) and deleted C5:D7 before selecting C3:D9 to copy and paste into the chart with Values (Y) in Columns and Categories (X Values) in First Column checked. This added the red dots.

For the black and the yellow dots I sorted copies of the data ascending for X and descending for X. In C3 copied across and down:

```
=AVERAGE(A11,A13)
```

and in C21 copied across and down:

```
=AVERAGE(A18,A20)
```

with C15:D15 and C22:D22 blanked out and C14:D16 and C21:D23 added to the chart as above.

To add yet more dots you could select ColumnsC and D, Copy, Paste Special..., Values over the top, merge C:D into A:B and repeat a process as above.

Comment: thanks for your help, i want to have more value/dots in the line, but using average function only allow me to get extra 1 value within 2 numbers. Is there anyway to generate more value within 2 numbers?